# Python package running locally but returning error when comes from PyPI

Tags: python, pip, pypi

anyone with experience in the creation and publication of Python packages on PyPI? cause I created a small package, a script more precisely and it was working perfectly so I published it to PyPI but now when I try to run the package from PyPI, it is returning:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/boris/.local/bin/quickrepo", line 7, in
>
> from quickrepo import main
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quickrepo'

Here is the content of `/home/boris/.local/bin/quickrepo:`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from quickrepo import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

FYI the code above doesn't figure in my project at all, I suppose PyPI generated an executable file.

Comment: Is [this](https://pypi.org/project/quickrepo) your module? If so, it looks like it's a command-line utility rather than something you'd import in another Python script.

Comment: I mean, am I supposed to publish it in a different way than a normal python module?

Comment: No, but my point is that you shouldn't need to import the module in another Python script since the module is meant to be used on the command line.

Comment: @BenSoyka that's the thing, I didn't write that code above [here](https://www.github.com/silverhairs/quickrepo) is the project repo.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I just forgot to add the package inside setup.py

```
    packages=['quickrepo'],
```

Comment: The `pymodules` line is wrong. This line would make sense if there was a `quickrepo.py` file directly at the root of the project, i.e. a `quickrepo` top-level module. Which doesn't seem to be the case. Additionally the `packages` line means that there is `quickrepo/__init__.py` file, i.e. a `quickrepo` top-level package, which seems to be the case. But you can't have both, that is not possible.

Comment: In my case, there is a `quickrepo/__init__.py` Let me correct then. Thanks @sinoroc